# Запретить скрипту обновлять содержимое control-а при наличии фокуса

Tags: javascript, html

Есть некая форма с различными input-ами (select, input), раз в секунду обновляемые через ajax (их значение может меняться не только от ввода пользователя, но и по своей внутренней логике на сервере). Проблема: когда пользователь устанавливает фокус на какой-либо input (начинает вводить число, например), скрипт раз в секунду сбрасывает его ввод на текущие значения сервера. Я обошёл это таким образом:
В коде страницы:

```
<select id="channel" onFocus="ControlDis[5]=1;" onBlur="ControlDis[5]=0;" onChange="this.blur();AJAXCmd('submit.cgi?channel='+this.value);">
```

В коде скрипта:

```
//вызывается раз в секунду (ajax)
function updateStatus(xmlData) {
var data=getJSONValue(xmlData);     
if(ControlDis[5]==0)document.getElementById('channel').value = data.misc.channel;
if(ControlDis[4]==0)document.getElementById('status').value = data.misc.status;
//подобным образом обновляем еще сотню разных элементов странички
}
```

Но этот способ, на мой взгляд, довольно корявый, и подвержен ошибкам. Нет ли чего поизящнее?

Comment: в чем вы измеряете изящность?

Comment: Сложно сказать. Просто я старый Сишник, и на Си сделал бы примерно так (ну индексы массива бы еще за-enum-ил). Но возможно у Javascript есть какая-то особенная, объектно-ориентированная магия?

Comment: а скрипт ваш? или сторонний?

Comment: Это embedded-сервер, он должен на страничке всякие индикаторы и бегунки показывать. Секунды даже мало, на самом деле. Но т.к. юзер предполагается в данный конкретный момент времени только один, это нормально. Про ООП это я пошутил, конечно.

Comment: Скрипт мой, да...

Comment: добавьте его в вопрос

Comment: @Keroronsk, ох-ох-ох :-D

Comment: еще сотня элементов тоже в `data.misc` лежит?

Comment: элементы в которых обновляются данные - только селекты или могут быть любые инпуты?

Comment: Нет, элементы "разложены" по разным объектам. data.status, data.messages etc. Элементы в которых обновляются данные могут быть практически любыми. Но проблемы возникают только с селектами и текстовыми полями (чекбокс невозможно вырвать из рук пользователя во время ввода).Поэтому проверку на ControlDis[] я делаю только на эти поля (чтоб вся страница не вставала колом, если пользователь начал печатать какое-то число в одном из инпутов). Впринципе, если мой подход вполне "легитимный", меня это устроит. Я пока новичок в JS, боюсь накодить какую-нибудь откровенную глупость.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35576/discussion-between-grundy-and-keroronsk).